# Shopware: PayPal is not showing up

Tags: shopware

I activated the PayPal Plugin setup the config and tested the connection. I set the payment active and added PayPal to my sales channel. Finally, I cleared the cache `bin/console cache:clear`.

Still, it is not visible for the customer.

Shopware v6.4.1.1 Stable Version

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser dev console or connections to PayPal servers?

Comment: Which Shopware version is this about?

Comment: I added the version above. Not errors.

Comment: Are there any rules assigned to the PayPal payment and is the payment entry activated?

Comment: Payment rule is set to "all customers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database I found the table `payment_method_translation` was missing the name for the PayPal plugin. After I set the name and cleared the cache I could select PayPal in the checkout.

[image]

Comment: How did that happen?

Comment: I would like to know that too.

Comment: I quickly installed Shopware 6.4.1.1 locally, default language = German, setup PayPal in the installer, and queried the `payment_method_translation` table. PayPal has both translations. So it does not seem to be a general bug. Maybe there was a problem in an earlier version and you did a update?